# Ubuntu installation: Find out where Grub and Windows bootloader sit

Tags: dual-boot, grub-efi, 16.10

I want to install Ubuntu 16.10 to replace my current 15.10 installation. I also have Windows 10 installed. The system is an EFI system.

Now my problem is that I remember from the last time I installed Ubuntu, that the whole bootloader situation was a bit messed up, which is why I now want to be extra careful, where I install Grub. However I cannot find out, where it is installed in my current setup and I do not want to risk ruining the Windows bootloader. How can I find out, where Grub sits at the moment, so that I can safely install it in the same place? I tried the boot info script, but that did not mention, where Grub sits.

This is the relevant output of `fdisk -l`:

```
Disk /dev/sda: 111,8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: E11DDD93-18E8-4DAA-8538-BB230F42C8BA

Gerät          Start      Ende  Sektoren  Size Typ
/dev/sda1       2048    206847    204800  100M EFI System
/dev/sda2     206848    468991    262144  128M Microsoft reserved
/dev/sda3     468992 191592447 191123456 91,1G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sda4  191592448 192514047    921600  450M Windows recovery environment
/dev/sda5  192514048 234440703  41926656   20G Linux filesystem


Disk /dev/sdb: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 95D46DE3-4D90-410A-960A-46B464AD04D9

Gerät           Start       Ende   Sektoren   Size Typ
/dev/sdb1        2048  585939547  585937500 279,4G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdb2   585940992 1933596671 1347655680 642,6G Linux filesystem
/dev/sdb3  1933596672 1953523711   19927040   9,5G Linux Swap
```

And this is what the boot info scrip says:

```
                  Boot Info Script 0.61      [1 April 2012]


============================= Boot Info Summary: ===============================

 => No boot loader is installed in the MBR of /dev/sda.
 => Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb.

sda1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       vfat
    Boot sector type:  Windows 7: FAT32
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /efi/Boot/bootx64.efi /efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi 
                       /efi/ubuntu/MokManager.efi /efi/ubuntu/shimx64.efi

sda2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Mounting failed:   mount: unknown filesystem type ''

sda3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        /Windows/System32/winload.exe

sda4: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sda5: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  Ubuntu 15.10
    Boot files:        /boot/grub/grub.cfg /etc/fstab

sdb1: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ntfs
    Boot sector type:  Windows Vista/7: NTFS
    Boot sector info:  No errors found in the Boot Parameter Block.
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb2: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       ext4
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 
    Operating System:  
    Boot files:        

sdb3: __________________________________________________________________________

    File system:       swap
    Boot sector type:  -
    Boot sector info: 

============================ Drive/Partition Info: =============================

Drive: sda _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sda: 111,8 GiB, 120034123776 bytes, 234441648 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sda1                   1   234,441,647   234,441,647  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sda1           2,048       206,847       204,800 EFI System partition
/dev/sda2         206,848       468,991       262,144 Microsoft Reserved Partition (Windows)
/dev/sda3         468,992   191,592,447   191,123,456 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sda4     191,592,448   192,514,047       921,600 Windows Recovery Environment (Windows)
/dev/sda5     192,514,048   234,440,703    41,926,656 Data partition (Linux)

Drive: sdb _____________________________________________________________________
Disk /dev/sdb: 931,5 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 4096 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt

Partition  Boot  Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors  Id System

/dev/sdb1                   1 1,953,525,167 1,953,525,167  ee GPT


GUID Partition Table detected.

Partition    Start Sector    End Sector  # of Sectors System
/dev/sdb1           2,048   585,939,547   585,937,500 Data partition (Windows/Linux)
/dev/sdb2     585,940,992 1,933,596,671 1,347,655,680 Data partition (Linux)
/dev/sdb3   1,933,596,672 1,953,523,711    19,927,040 Swap partition (Linux)

"blkid" output: ________________________________________________________________

Device           UUID                                   TYPE       LABEL

/dev/sda1        6EF5-751D                              vfat       
/dev/sda2                                                          
/dev/sda3        2A1808F61808C2B5                       ntfs       
/dev/sda4        0C3E6CED3E6CD16E                       ntfs       
/dev/sda5        03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9   ext4       
/dev/sdb1        6431D7B521AC29B4                       ntfs       windata
/dev/sdb2        3afe68aa-02f4-45c5-b786-c6a39e2d0690   ext4       
/dev/sdb3        1128331f-ebcf-4d3d-81e4-b9da91fa736b   swap       

================================ Mount points: =================================

Device           Mount_Point              Type       Options

/dev/sda1        /boot/efi                vfat       (rw,relatime,fmask=0077,dmask=0077,codepage=437,iocharset=iso8859-1,shortname=mixed,errors=remount-ro)
/dev/sda5        /                        ext4       (rw,relatime,errors=remount-ro,data=ordered)
/dev/sdb2        /home                    ext4       (rw,relatime,data=ordered)


=========================== sda5/boot/grub/grub.cfg: ===========================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
#
# DO NOT EDIT THIS FILE
#
# It is automatically generated by grub-mkconfig using templates
# from /etc/grub.d and settings from /etc/default/grub
#

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/00_header ###
if [ -s $prefix/grubenv ]; then
  set have_grubenv=true
  load_env
fi
if [ "${next_entry}" ] ; then
   set default="${next_entry}"
   set next_entry=
   save_env next_entry
   set boot_once=true
else
   set default="0"
fi

if [ x"${feature_menuentry_id}" = xy ]; then
  menuentry_id_option="--id"
else
  menuentry_id_option=""
fi

export menuentry_id_option

if [ "${prev_saved_entry}" ]; then
  set saved_entry="${prev_saved_entry}"
  save_env saved_entry
  set prev_saved_entry=
  save_env prev_saved_entry
  set boot_once=true
fi

function savedefault {
  if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then
    saved_entry="${chosen}"
    save_env saved_entry
  fi
}
function recordfail {
  set recordfail=1
  if [ -n "${have_grubenv}" ]; then if [ -z "${boot_once}" ]; then save_env recordfail; fi; fi
}
function load_video {
  if [ x$feature_all_video_module = xy ]; then
    insmod all_video
  else
    insmod efi_gop
    insmod efi_uga
    insmod ieee1275_fb
    insmod vbe
    insmod vga
    insmod video_bochs
    insmod video_cirrus
  fi
}

if [ x$feature_default_font_path = xy ] ; then
   font=unicode
else
insmod part_gpt
insmod ext2
set root='hd0,gpt5'
if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9
else
  search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9
fi
    font="/usr/share/grub/unicode.pf2"
fi

if loadfont $font ; then
  set gfxmode=auto
  load_video
  insmod gfxterm
  set locale_dir=$prefix/locale
  set lang=de_DE
  insmod gettext
fi
terminal_output gfxterm
if [ "${recordfail}" = 1 ] ; then
  set timeout=30
else
  if [ x$feature_timeout_style = xy ] ; then
    set timeout_style=menu
    set timeout=10
  # Fallback normal timeout code in case the timeout_style feature is
  # unavailable.
  else
    set timeout=10
  fi
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/00_header ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###
set menu_color_normal=white/black
set menu_color_highlight=black/light-gray
if background_color 44,0,30,0; then
  clear
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/05_debian_theme ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###
function gfxmode {
    set gfxpayload="${1}"
    if [ "${1}" = "keep" ]; then
        set vt_handoff=vt.handoff=7
    else
        set vt_handoff=
    fi
}
if [ "${recordfail}" != 1 ]; then
  if [ -e ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt ]; then
    if hwmatch ${prefix}/gfxblacklist.txt 3; then
      if [ ${match} = 0 ]; then
        set linux_gfx_mode=keep
      else
        set linux_gfx_mode=text
      fi
    else
      set linux_gfx_mode=text
    fi
  else
    set linux_gfx_mode=keep
  fi
else
  set linux_gfx_mode=text
fi
export linux_gfx_mode
menuentry 'Ubuntu' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-simple-03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9' {
    recordfail
    load_video
    gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
    insmod gzio
    if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod ext2
    set root='hd0,gpt5'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9
    fi
    linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-42-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
    initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-42-generic
}
submenu 'Erweiterte Optionen für Ubuntu' $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-advanced-03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9' {
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 4.2.0-42-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-42-generic-advanced-03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9
        fi
        echo    'Linux 4.2.0-42-generic wird geladen …'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-42-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Initiale Ramdisk wird geladen …'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-42-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-42-generic (upstart)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-42-generic-init-upstart-03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9
        fi
        echo    'Linux 4.2.0-42-generic wird geladen …'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-42-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff init=/sbin/upstart
        echo    'Initiale Ramdisk wird geladen …'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-42-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-42-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-42-generic-recovery-03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9
        fi
        echo    'Linux 4.2.0-42-generic wird geladen …'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-42-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Initiale Ramdisk wird geladen …'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-42-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, mit Linux 4.2.0-41-generic' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-41-generic-advanced-03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9
        fi
        echo    'Linux 4.2.0-41-generic wird geladen …'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-41-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff
        echo    'Initiale Ramdisk wird geladen …'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-41-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-41-generic (upstart)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-41-generic-init-upstart-03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        gfxmode $linux_gfx_mode
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9
        fi
        echo    'Linux 4.2.0-41-generic wird geladen …'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-41-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9 ro  quiet splash $vt_handoff init=/sbin/upstart
        echo    'Initiale Ramdisk wird geladen …'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-41-generic
    }
    menuentry 'Ubuntu, with Linux 4.2.0-41-generic (recovery mode)' --class ubuntu --class gnu-linux --class gnu --class os $menuentry_id_option 'gnulinux-4.2.0-41-generic-recovery-03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9' {
        recordfail
        load_video
        insmod gzio
        if [ x$grub_platform = xxen ]; then insmod xzio; insmod lzopio; fi
        insmod part_gpt
        insmod ext2
        set root='hd0,gpt5'
        if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt5 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt5 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt5  03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9
        else
          search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9
        fi
        echo    'Linux 4.2.0-41-generic wird geladen …'
        linux   /boot/vmlinuz-4.2.0-41-generic.efi.signed root=UUID=03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9 ro recovery nomodeset 
        echo    'Initiale Ramdisk wird geladen …'
        initrd  /boot/initrd.img-4.2.0-41-generic
    }
}

### END /etc/grub.d/10_linux ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### END /etc/grub.d/20_linux_xen ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###
### END /etc/grub.d/20_memtest86+ ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###
menuentry 'Windows Boot Manager (auf /dev/sda1)' --class windows --class os $menuentry_id_option 'osprober-efi-6EF5-751D' {
    insmod part_gpt
    insmod fat
    set root='hd0,gpt1'
    if [ x$feature_platform_search_hint = xy ]; then
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root --hint-bios=hd0,gpt1 --hint-efi=hd0,gpt1 --hint-baremetal=ahci0,gpt1  6EF5-751D
    else
      search --no-floppy --fs-uuid --set=root 6EF5-751D
    fi
    chainloader /EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi
}
set timeout_style=menu
if [ "${timeout}" = 0 ]; then
  set timeout=10
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/30_os-prober ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###
menuentry 'System setup' $menuentry_id_option 'uefi-firmware' {
    fwsetup
}
### END /etc/grub.d/30_uefi-firmware ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###
# This file provides an easy way to add custom menu entries.  Simply type the
# menu entries you want to add after this comment.  Be careful not to change
# the 'exec tail' line above.
### END /etc/grub.d/40_custom ###

### BEGIN /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
if [ -f  ${config_directory}/custom.cfg ]; then
  source ${config_directory}/custom.cfg
elif [ -z "${config_directory}" -a -f  $prefix/custom.cfg ]; then
  source $prefix/custom.cfg;
fi
### END /etc/grub.d/41_custom ###
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=============================== sda5/etc/fstab: ================================

--------------------------------------------------------------------------------
# /etc/fstab: static file system information.
#
# Use 'blkid' to print the universally unique identifier for a
# device; this may be used with UUID= as a more robust way to name devices
# that works even if disks are added and removed. See fstab(5).
#
# <file system> <mount point>   <type>  <options>       <dump>  <pass>
# / was on /dev/sda5 during installation
UUID=03a4142e-656d-4063-a212-8d7ff0124be9 /               ext4    errors=remount-ro 0       1
# /boot/efi was on /dev/sda1 during installation
UUID=6EF5-751D  /boot/efi       vfat    umask=0077      0       1
# /home was on /dev/sdb2 during installation
UUID=3afe68aa-02f4-45c5-b786-c6a39e2d0690 /home           ext4    defaults        0       2
# swap was on /dev/sdb3 during installation
UUID=1128331f-ebcf-4d3d-81e4-b9da91fa736b none            swap    sw              0       0
/dev/disk/by-uuid/2A1808F61808C2B5 /mnt/2A1808F61808C2B5 auto nosuid,nodev,nofail,noauto 0 0
--------------------------------------------------------------------------------

=================== sda5: Location of files loaded by Grub: ====================

           GiB - GB             File                                 Fragment(s)


=============================== StdErr Messages: ===============================

cat: /tmp/BootInfo-qZ45TXCy/Tmp_Log: Datei oder Verzeichnis nicht gefunden
```

This is the output of `efibootmgr -v`:

```
BootCurrent: 0001
Timeout: 2 seconds
BootOrder: 0001,0000,0002
Boot0000* Windows Boot Manager  HD(1,GPT,9ffc789a-2364-433e-a852-797fd3b7da5b,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Microsoft\Boot\bootmgfw.efi)WINDOWS.........x...B.C.D.O.B.J.E.C.T.=.{.9.d.e.a.8.6.2.c.-.5.c.d.d.-.4.e.7.0.-.a.c.c.1.-.f.3.2.b.3.4.4.d.4.7.9.5.}...a................
Boot0001* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,9ffc789a-2364-433e-a852-797fd3b7da5b,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\ubuntu\shimx64.efi)
Boot0002* ubuntu    HD(1,GPT,9ffc789a-2364-433e-a852-797fd3b7da5b,0x800,0x32000)/File(\EFI\Ubuntu\grubx64.efi)
```

Though the script says that Windows is installed in the MBR of /dev/sdb, I think that it sits in /dev/sda1.

The Grub boot menu has an entry to the Windows Bootloader (not Windows itself, it specifically mentions the bootloader), which according to the menu entry is in /dev/sda1

Comment: You show a Windows type BIOS boot loader in sdb, but both sda & sdb are gpt. Windows only boots in UEFI mode from gpt partitioned drives. But script did not show the /EFI/Microsoft folder in the ESP - efi system partition. Did script just not show it? Better to always post link to full Summary Report from Boot-Repair. Does Windows actually boot from UEFI boot menu? You did not show if Windows in grub menu which link  to full report would also show.

Comment: @oldfred I added the full boot info output

Comment: Grub found the Windows folder, so is it really there and not in script?

Comment: What do you mean? The grub menu script says that the win bootloader is in sda1, yet the script finds bootable stuff in sda3 (the main win partition), but also says that win is installed in the MBR of sdb

Comment: With UEFI most of the boot loader 'stuff' (highly technical term)  is in the ESP - efi system partition.

Comment: which is sda1 and the script finds some linux-y boot information there. But it makes me nervous that the windows boot manager could potentially also sit there according to the grub menu entry. If I reinstall now and install grub into sda1, will that not erase the windows bootloader in case it is also located there?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Before proceeding further, you may want to review some information on how EFI-mode booting works. I recommend:

- **[Adam Williamson's blog entry on how EFI works](https://www.happyassassin.net/2014/01/25/uefi-boot-how-does-that-actually-work-then/)** -- This page describes the theory behind EFI-mode booting.
- **[A question and answers on the differences between BIOS and EFI booting on Superuser.com](https://superuser.com/questions/496026/what-is-the-difference-in-boot-with-bios-and-boot-with-uefi)** -- This provides the basics of the preceding, but is more concise.
- **[My page on installing Linux on EFI systems](http://www.rodsbooks.com/linux-uefi/)** -- This page is a more practical introduction to EFI-mode booting than Adam Williamson's blog. This is geared towards initial installations, but may still be helpful to you.

Some specific observations about your Boot Info Script output:

- Both your disks use the [GUID Partition Table (GPT).](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/GUID_Partition_Table) Windows cannot boot from a GPT disk in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode; it must do so in EFI/UEFI mode.
- Your [EFI System Partition (ESP)](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/EFI_System_partition) is `/dev/sda1`. The ESP holds EFI-mode boot loaders.
- Your ESP contains the Ubuntu GRUB 2 boot loader (`/efi/ubuntu/grubx64.efi`) and related files (`shimx64.efi` and `MokManager.efi`). It also holds `efi/Boot/bootx64.efi`, which could be anything -- perhaps the Windows boot manager, perhaps another copy of GRUB, perhaps something else.
- Your `/dev/sda` holds no BIOS-mode boot loader.
- Your `/dev/sdb` contains a BIOS-mode version of the Windows boot loader.
- Your `grub.cfg` contains one entry for booting Windows, which launches `/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` (which is the usual name and location for the Windows EFI boot loader) on `/dev/sda1`; however, the Boot Info Script does not show this file as existing. Sometimes Boot Info Script misses files, so it could be that a Boot Info Script bug explains this discrepancy. I recommend you check this manually by looking for `/boot/efi/EFI/Microsoft/Boot/bootmgfw.efi` in Ubuntu. (The ESP is mounted at `/boot/efi` in Ubuntu by default.)
- Your Boot Info Script output lacks output from `efibootmgr -v`. This output is normally included when you boot in EFI mode. If you ran the Boot Info Script from an emergency disk, then that could explain this discrepancy. If you ran it from a normal boot, it's puzzling, but not puzzling enough for me to recommend you do anything about it, at least not by itself.

Overall, it looks like you're booting both OSes in EFI mode, and the Boot Info Script has simply failed to locate the Windows boot manager. My hunch is that the BIOS-mode Windows boot loader in the MBR of `/dev/sdb` is simply left over from a previous installation; or perhaps you installed it in BIOS mode but then followed a procedure to convert it to an EFI-mode installation. Either way, it's harmless except for the fact that it raises questions about how things are installed.

In either event, you should be able to upgrade simply by following the usual upgrade procedures. Note that the prompt for where to install the boot loader is *ignored* when doing an EFI-mode install, so your concern about this is misplaced. I do have a few suggestions, though:

- Instead of installing 16.10, you might want to consider 16.04 (or 16.04.1) LTS, which is often more stable. You should also be able to upgrade to 16.04 from within your current installation by using the `do-release-upgrade` program.
- I ***STRONGLY*** recommend backing up as much of your computer as you can before proceeding. At a *minimum,* back up the ESP (`/dev/sda1`; `/boot/efi`) and your personal files (probably `/home` and wherever you store your personal files in Windows). OS installations and upgrades can go smoothly and create no problems; but if you slip up in some important way, you could end up trashing all your personal files and/or the Windows boot loader. Backing these up before doing anything is advisable.
- If you upgrade using an Ubuntu installation medium, and if your system is configured to permit either BIOS-mode or EFI-mode booting, reconfigure it to permit only EFI-mode booting. Details of how to do this vary from one computer to another. Since you're currently booting both your OSes in EFI mode, BIOS-mode support is doing you no good, and could create complications if you accidentally boot the Ubuntu installer in BIOS mode. See [my page on this subject](http://www.rodsbooks.com/efi-bootloaders/csm-good-bad-ugly.html) for more details.
- Read at least one, and ideally all three, of the links I posted at the start of this answer. Understanding the EFI boot process is your best bet for avoiding disastrous problems when setting up or upgrading your system.

Comment: Thank you for the comprehensive answer. I added the output of `efibootmgr -v`. I did run the boot info script from a normal boot.

Comment: Just to double check: When I try to install ubuntu (with the "something else" option), it specifically asks me, where to put the bootloader. Now you say this is ignored?

Comment: Also during installation on the partition screen, `/dev/sda1`is called "Windows Boot Manager". I think this does not really mean anything? From reading your links I understand that there can be multiple bootloaders in one ESP, so there is not much to do wrong, because Ubuntu just puts its bootloader next to possibly existing ones?

Comment: Your `/dev/sda1` is the EFI System Partition (ESP). It *contains* the Windows boot loader/manager, but `/dev/sda1` should not be labeled "Windows boot manager." Without a screen shot or exact and complete quote, I can't comment further on such labeling; it could be a program bug, the label might be unclear, you might be misinterpreting something, etc.

Comment: Worked like a charm, nothing to worry about. Thank you!

Answer (score -2):

> Disklabel type: gpt

so 2mb special part missed.fdisk's   `BIOS boot`.

you still can install it sometimes,but not by the common way.

think parted `p` may show more.
So  legacy BIOS-compatibility mode cant be used and last chance to boot is uefi.

Comment: Attempting to boot the system described by the Boot Info Script output shown in BIOS/CSM/legacy mode will not work, and attempting to set up or modify a BIOS-mode boot loader for it is likely to create new problems. It's an EFI/UEFI-mode system, although the Boot Info Script seems to have missed some Windows boot files, so there's some uncertainty about some important details.

Comment: As i unerstand there is no problem on scene for now,but just afraid of.

Comment: I dont understand what you beware of.There is `EFI System` bay with `grubx64.efi` .And what?